# Get Python arguments using Jython in Java

Tags: java, python, jython

I am trying to parse a python script to get the functions names and their arguments, I need to do it using java.

I managed to get their names using Jython but I can't find any way to get their arguments (name, number of them?).

Python example :

```
def multiply_by_two(number):
    """Returns the given number multiplied by two

    The result is always a floating point number.
    This keyword fails if the given `number` cannot be converted to number.
    """
    return float(number) * 2

def numbers_should_be_equal(first, second):
    print '*DEBUG* Got arguments %s and %s' % (first, second)
    if float(first) != float(second):
```

Java code:

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.execfile(file.getAbsolutePath());
PyStringMap map=(PyStringMap)interpreter.getLocals();
for (Object key : map.keys()) {
    Object o=map.get(Py.java2py(key));                          
    if (o instanceof PyFunction) {
        System.out.println((String)key); // the function name
        PyFunction function = (PyFunction) o; 
    }
}
```

I start to lose hope about finding a way to do it...

If anyone have an idea, even without using Jython

Thank you

Comment: Would doing in in python using [`inspect.getargspec()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) be an option, e.g. after execfile do something like `interpreter.exec("import inspect"); PyStringMap map=(PyStringMap)interpreter.eval("dict([(k, inspect.getargspec(v)) for (k, v) in locals().items() if inspect.isfunction(v)])
")`

Comment: Perfect ! I definitly didn't had the right mindset to use jython inside java. I will add an answer with your answer to close the topic. But you can also add afterward your comment in an answer for you to have the accepted answer ! Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44285551/get-python-arguments-using-jython-in-java/44414570#comment75622412_44285551) from [mata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350899/mata):

> > Would doing in in python using inspect.getargspec() be an option, e.g.
> >     after execfile do something like
>
> ```
> interpreter.exec("import inspect"); PyStringMap map=(PyStringMap)interpreter.eval("dict([(k, inspect.getargspec(v))
> for (k, v) in locals().items() if inspect.isfunction(v)]) ")
> ```

Here is the working code:

```
PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
interpreter.execfile(file.getAbsolutePath());
interpreter.exec("import inspect"); 
PyDictionary dico=(PyDictionary) interpreter.eval("dict([(k, inspect.getargspec(v).args) for (k, v) in locals().items() if inspect.isfunction(v)])"); 
ConcurrentMap<PyObject, PyObject> map= dico.getMap();
map.forEach((k,v)->{
    System.out.println(k.toString());   
    System.out.println(v.toString());   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The internal `__code__` dictionary attribute of functions has a `co_varnames` tuple attribute for function variable names, for example:

```
def t(t1, t2): pass
t.__code__.co_nlocals

>>>  ('t1', 't2')
```

There is also `t.__defaults__` for keyword arguments with defaults.

As `__code__` is internal implementation though, it is subject to change across interpreters. AFAIK, it is part of specification as of Python 2.6+.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am trying to achieve it but it seem that there is no __code__ attribute for PyFunction in Jython, another attribute func_code does exist:                                                                           PyFunction function = (PyFunction) o;                                                    
PyCode code = function.func_code;                                                                    but it trigger this error:  java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: func_code

Comment: Indeed, there is no `__code__` in Jython according to API documentation. `__getnewargs__` perhaps? - http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/core/PyObject.html#__getnewargs__()

Comment: Unfortunatly no it doesn't work either. In fact __code__ apear in this docs http://static.javadoc.io/org.python/jython/2.7.0/org/python/core/PyFunction.html but not in this one http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/core/PyFunction.html which correpond to what I have (I use the 2.7 standalone jar), do you have any idea to why there is this difference of filed in the two docs ?

Comment: The one on [jython.org](http://www.jython.org/javadoc/org/python/core/PyFunction.html) is for the `2.5` API specification, which explains why `__code__` is missing. See [docs page on jython site](http://www.jython.org/docs/index.html). The one on [javadoc](http://static.javadoc.io/org.python/jython/2.7.0/org/python/core/PyFunction.html) is for `2.7` which should match the 2.7 jython jar - `__code__` should be there in other words.

Comment: I managed to get the _code_ attribute from the PyFunction but there is notco_varname or co_nlocals...